# How could I combine 3 txt file together

Tags: python, python-3.x, file

I've made 3 text files with 1 or 2 sentences inside.

I know how to readlines inside txt file and combine them altogether.

I have no idea how to combine all the sentences.

ex) If sentences are A,B,C

Results might be A B C or A C B or C B A or B C A ...

I have 10 sentence and wanna combine 6 of them randomly.

```
def output() :          
     infile=open("file.txt","r")
     outfile=open("outputone.txt","w")

     line= open('outputa1.txt').readlines()
     line=''.join(line)
     outfile.write("\n")

def output1() :

     line= open('outputa2.txt').readlines()
     line=''.join(line)
     outfile.write(line)
     outfile.write("\n")

def output2() :

     line= open('outputa3.txt').readlines()
     line=''.join(line)
     outfile.write(line)
     outfile.write("\n")

     infile.close()
     outfile.close()

output()
output1()
output2()
```

These are my code if you have any ideas please help me !!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you want to permute the lines for selecting 6 random lines. I think by permutation you mean shuffling. Permutation of 10 lines will give you 3628800 combinations of the lines. So I am giving a solution to randomly select 6 lines from 10 lines and write it into a file.

outputa1.txt:

1. This is file 1
2. This is foo
3. This is the end of file 1

outputa2.txt

1. This is file 2
2. This is bar
3. This is the end of file 2

outputa3.tx

1. This is file 3
2. This is baz
3. This is the end of file 3
4. That's all

Now these three files combined will have 10 lines.

```
import random
combined_lines = []
f = open('outputa1.txt','r')
for line in f:
    combined_lines.append(line+'\n')
f.close()
f = open('outputa2.txt','r')
for line in f:
    combined_lines.append(line+'\n')
f.close()
f = open('outputa3.txt','r')
for line in f:
    combined_lines.append(line+'\n')
f.close()
#To choose randomly 6 lines from the file
random.shuffle(combined_lines)
f = open('outputa.txt','x')
f.writelines(combined_lines[:6])
f.close()
```